# Downloading excel file from Google Cloud storage returns a buffer, how can I return the actual excel file so I can write to it in my handler?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, fs

I'm trying to retrieve an excel file from my bucket using the Firebase Admin SDK using the following code:

```js
export const getTemplate = async (fileName: string) => {
  const filePath = admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .file('sheets/template.xlsx')

  const [file] = await filePath.download()
  return file
}
```

I then pass what's returned from this function, to this function:

```js
export const writeToTemplate = (
  objects: any[],
  sheetNames: string[],
  file
) => {

  objects.forEach((dataObject, index) => {
    const sheetName = sheetNames[index]
    const worksheet = templateFile.Sheets[sheetName]
    utils.sheet_add_json(worksheet, dataObject)
  })
  return file
}
```

However this throws an error that it cannot read my file. When I console log the file it shows a buffer

`<Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00.........>`

How can I actually write to the file? Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to read the `Buffer` with the `read` function from the `xlsx` package.